# How to retrieve the local storage value after refresh the page in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I put the input values into web local storage.

But my need is, to access the local storage value into the ng-model.

After click the submit button, local storage values to be append in table row.

I tried but it doesnot happen.

Please refer the below code.

```js
  

var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", ["ngStorage"]);
helloApp.controller("CompanyCtrl", function($scope, $localStorage) {

  $scope.companies = [{
    'name': 'Xerago Technologies',
    'employees': 125000,
    'headoffice': 'Bangalore'
  }, {
    'name': 'Cognizant Technologies',
    'employees': 100000,
    'headoffice': 'Bangalore'
  }, {
    'name': 'Wipro',
    'employees': 115000,
    'headoffice': 'Bangalore'
  }, {
    'name': 'Tata Consultancy Services (TCS)',
    'employees': 150000,
    'headoffice': 'Bangalore'
  }, {
    'name': 'HCL Technologies',
    'employees': 90000,
    'headoffice': 'Noida'
  }, ];
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.message = {
      'name': $scope.name,
      'employees': $scope.employees,
      'headoffice': $scope.headoffice
    };
 $scope.companies.push($localStorage.message);
  
    console.log($localStorage.message);
    
  };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>

<div ng-app="helloApp" ng-controller="CompanyCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name
      </th>
      <th>Employees
      </th>
      <th>Head Office
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
      <td>{{company.name}}
      </td>
      <td>{{company.employees}}
      </td>
      <td>{{company.headoffice}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Employees</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employees" ng-model="employees" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Headoffice</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="headoffice" ng-model="headoffice" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div style="padding-left:110px">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now i can able to push the input values in table and also available in local storage..

But when i refresh the page, the last updated data hides. I think i need to know how to get.

Please help on this.

Comment: why are you pre-pending $ to localStorage? use it as normal

Comment: like localStorage.setItem("key",value) and localStorage.getItem("key");

Comment: why do you need localStorage in the first place?

Comment: @AnkushJain, OP is using [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) Hence using `$localStorage` service and You can retrieve/store using `$localStorage.key`

Comment: @AnkushJain - You answer it as javascript way. but he go with angular way.

Comment: Sorry i put the wrong code previous....

Comment: Check if the data is present in the localstorage first. (Chrome -> F12 ->  Application ->localStorage) 

Seems the save function is wrong? Can you check that again.

Comment: Yeah its present.. already checked.. I dont know how to retrieve(or) append the values into table row.

Comment: @nevin its not placing.. if i remove data object in ng-model means it will work

Comment: It will appear in local storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : as local storage will not work here, so you need to check from demo link at out side : 
So try this link : [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LVToqFwcehDDgD0Sl1ha?p=preview)

```js
  var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", []);
  helloApp.controller("CompanyCtrl", function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.companies = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('compnyData'));
    console.log($scope.companies);

    $scope.addRow = function() {
      $scope.message = {
        'name': $scope.name,
        'employees': $scope.employees,
        'headoffice': $scope.headoffice
      };
      $scope.name = '';
      $scope.employees = '';
      $scope.headoffice = '';

      var tempCompanies = [];
      var tempData = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('compnyData'));
      console.log(tempData);
      if (tempData != null) {
        console.log('not null');
        tempData.push($scope.message);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('compnyData', JSON.stringify(tempData));
        $scope.companies = tempData;
      } else {
        $window.localStorage.setItem('compnyData', JSON.stringify([$scope.message]));
        $scope.companies = [$scope.message];
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="helloApp" ng-controller="CompanyCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name
      </th>
      <th>Employees
      </th>
      <th>Head Office
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
      <td>{{company.name}}
      </td>
      <td>{{company.employees}}
      </td>
      <td>{{company.headoffice}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Employees</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employees" ng-model="employees" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Headoffice</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="headoffice" ng-model="headoffice" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div style="padding-left:110px">
      <input type="button" ng-click="addRow()" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you please how to define in ng-model

Comment: oK jigar @jigar

Comment: Ok now i think i am done with that, just updating my answer, but i have made one js fiddle for you, you have to check by demo link as local storage will not work in stack overflow, so check it there and let me know.

Comment: give me more 5 mins i am making demo link outside for you. Will post it in my answer.

Comment: now you can check my demo link from answer, check everything from local storage also, let me know.

Comment: Refresh again and check demo link.

Comment: you can delete , add everything from local storage manually and check , when you will refresh the page it will be still there and fetch record from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126715/discussion-between-idris-and-jigar7521).

Answer (score 1):

you need to use set and get properties for localstorage to save and retrive your data.

assign your new data to message

```
 $scope.message = {'name':$scope.name, 'employees': $scope.employees, 'headoffice':$scope.headoffice};
```

to set the data in localstorage.....

```
localStorage.setItem("newData",$scope.message);
```

to get the data on click.....

```
localStorage.getItem("newData");
```

Comment: cant able to get the data.

Comment: there is no issue in that